# Calculating $\lim_{x \to 0} [(x+1)^x-1]^x$

Tags: limits

How the following limit can be calculated:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} [(x+1)^x-1]^x$$ ?

I've estimated the $0^0$ limit by writing the function under the form $e^
{\ln\{...\}}$. Then, by applying twice l'Hospital rule, I've found the limit is 1.

I need help in order to obviate these large calculations.

Comment: Have you been taught the $0^0$ form? This is one application of it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE!
Try to provide context if applicable, and to show the attempts that you made yourself. That will make bring much more attention to your question!

Comment: Of course, but the estimates were difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by Taylor's expansions

- $\log (1+x)=x+o(x)$
- $e^x=1+x+o(x)$

we have

$$(1+x)^x=e^{x\log(1+x)}=e^{x^2+o(x^2)}=1+x^2+o(x^2)$$

thus

$$[(x+1)^x-1] ^x=[1+x^2+o(x^2)-1] ^x=(x^2+o(x^2))^x=e^{x(\log x^2+o(x^2))}\to 1$$

indeed

$$x[\log x^2+o(x^2)]=x[\log x^2+\log (1+o(1))]=2x\log x+x\log(1+o(1))\to0+0=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Compute first the limit of the log: $\;x\ln\bigl((x+1)^x-1\bigr)$.

We'll make an asymptotic expansion of $\;(x+1)^x$ near $0$:
$$ (x+1)^x=\mathrm e^{x\ln(1+x)}=\mathrm e^{x(x+o(x))}=\mathrm e^{x^2+o(x^2)}=1+x^2+o(x^2)\quad\text{(by composition)}, $$

\begin{align}
\text{so}\hspace6em x\ln\bigl((x+1)^x-1\bigr)&=x\ln\bigl(x^2+o(x^2)\bigr)=x\ln\bigl(x^2(1+o(1))\bigr)\qquad\qquad\\
&=2x\ln x+x\underbrace{\ln\bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)}_{\substack{\downarrow\\0}} \\
&=\underbrace{2x\ln x+o(x)}_{\substack{\downarrow\\0}}.
\end{align}
As the log tends to $0$, $\;\lim_{x\to 0}\bigl((x+1)^x-1\bigr)^x=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Write your limit in the form
$$\exp\left[\lim_{x\to 0}\left[x\ln((x+1)^x-1)\right]\right]$$

Comment: Is it possible to use a bigger font here? Most of the important stuff in superscript is really small :(

Comment: @GaurangTandon press Ctr and +.

Comment: @orole Great point, but I was hoping for a built-in mathjax command :)

Comment: `\displaystyle` gives $$e^{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\ln((x+1)^x-1)x}$$ which feels 'unbalanced'. I think the better solution is to use `\exp` instead of `e`.